# Importing non-code asset (.png) from Javascript in Parcel 2 displays ts error

Tags: typescript, babeljs, parceljs

I am using [Parcel v2](https://v2.parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/#importing-non-code-assets-from-javascript) bundler. It says the following about import static files:

> If you want import the url to an image (or a soundfile, etc.) from Javascript, you need to prepend url: to the module specifier (read more about named pipelines in [Plugin Configuration](https://v2.parceljs.org/configuration/plugin-configuration/#predefined-(offical)-named-pipelines))

I have tried adding `url:` and also the standard method from v1. The image is bundled correctly, but I keep getting this ts error:

> Cannot find module 'url:../assets/parcel.png' or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)

[image: error ts(2307) is VSCode]

I have the following `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react",
    },
}
```

Since Parcel bundles without issues, I am assuming this is related to some missing TypeScript configuration. Would you please confirm this?

Comment: Please include errors as text, not as pictures of text.

Comment: Same problem here 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this is what is happening, from [TypeScript: Handbook, Working with Other JavaScript Libraries](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries):

> To describe the shape of libraries not written in TypeScript, we need to declare the API that the library exposes.
>
> We call declarations that don’t define an implementation “ambient”. Typically, these are defined in .d.ts files. If you’re familiar with C/C++, you can think of these as .h files.

Creating a `.d.ts` in your root directory with the following content should do the work:

```
declare module 'url:*' {
  export default string;
}
```

For any further questions or issues, please refer to this [discussion](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/discussions/5194#discussioncomment-86432) in Parcel's Github.